# I could not download any app from windows phone?

Tags: windows-10-mobile

From store I am trying to download whatsapp but it is showing starting download since 1 hour.I cannot delete the app from downloads.Please anyone can help me.

Comment: Hello i need it very important.Please solve my issue.

Comment: I could not download whatsapp it is showing starting download from morning wifi connection is fine but it is not downloading what is the problem.Please suggest me.

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: No error message.it is just showing starting download from morning

Comment: So this is the same problem as http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/12089/how-to-cancel-app-downloads-in-store?

Comment: Not only whatsapp for all apps it is showing same.My ineternet connection is fine.

Comment: there is  no solution what it mean??

Comment: why it is duplicate i cannot download phone updates also.

Comment: This question is "I can't download *this* app"; The other question is "I can't download *any* app" - If a rmeedy is found for one, I would expect it to fix the other