# How to cancel app downloads in Store?

Tags: store, windows-10-mobile

I cannot cancel an app download from the Store. It's been showing "starting download" for 1-2 hours already, and there is no Cancel button. Please help me, I need to install the app.

Comment: Not sure if this works on W10M, but on WP8.1 it's just a press-and-hold on the app to cancel

Comment: In win10 it is not working and the app is showing pending as the wifi signal is full and i can open in another phone and it is showing problem in my phone.Please suggest me.

Comment: Have you checked the time and date on your phone are correct?

Comment: yes it is fine and correct time.

Comment: @RowlandShaw hello what hpn give me reply.Please solve my problem.

Comment: Resetting the phone will it works

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10 Mobile there are two buttons when an app is downloading: Pause and Cancel. These are shown to the right of the app name (same as on desktop). However, if the download does not start correctly or doesn't succeed these buttons will not be visible, which it sounds like is happening for you.

Answer (score 2):

This has happened to me as well and this is how I fixed it. First, I turned my phone off and back on again. Make sure you see the message:

> Slide down to power off

Second, I opened the store app. After a couple of minutes, eventually the cancel button, which in Windows mobile 10 is an `X`, appeared for me to use.

In case it helps, I also found that I could cancel other downloads from the bottom of the list after rebooting the phone rather than starting from the top. However once you get the error, none of the other cancel buttons work. It is time to reboot again.